# DataFrame view in PyCharm when using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I create a pyspark dataframe and i want to see it in the SciView tab in PyCharm when i debug my code (like I used to do when i have worked with pandas).
It says "Nothing to show" (the dataframe exists, I can see it when I use the show() command).

someone knows how to do it or maybe there is no integration between pycharm and pyspark dataframe in this case?

Comment: Beware that any such action if possible will mean collecting data from all executor into driver memory...which for large data size may result into crash...show/head etc. are safer alternative to just show sample data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pycharm does not support spark dataframes, you should call the `toPandas()` method on the dataframe. As @abhiieor mentioned in a comment, be aware that you can potentially collect a lot of data, you should first `limit()` the number of rows returned.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/BDIDE-2399/ feature request for the support in Big Data Tools plugin.